# Diaplaying annotation pin with different colours for 2 sets of latitudes and longitudes

Tags: iphone

i have 4 arrays, 2 arrays consists of the hotel latitude and longitude values
 and rest arrays consists of the attraction latitude and longitude values.i can display them in map.but iam unable to differenciate the annoation pin colour of hotels and attarction......

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: (here i believe you can differentiate among the two distinct type off entity for which you want to annotate).

```
MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MyPin"];  
annView.animatesDrop=FALSE;
annView.canShowCallout = YES;
[annView setSelected:YES];

 //YOU CAN CHANGE IMAGE:
if (kSCEntityTypeFirst) {
    annView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"SMTL_home_tooltip_red_icon~iphone.png"];
}
else {
    annView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"SMTL_home_tooltip_blue_icon~iphone.png"];

}

 //YOU CAN CHANGE COLOR:
if (kSCEntityTypeFirst) {
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
}
else {
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
}
```

Comment: may i know what is kSCEntityTypeFirst?

Comment: it's your hotel or attraction what you consider it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use settag for annotaion at the time of adding to map view and in the method viewForAnnotaion you can set the different images by getting the TAG values using such if condition or switch cases